# How to access custom named views in Zend controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How to get access to the custom named views instead of giving the same method name in Zend framework 2.0.

For Eg:

Under index action "return new ViewModel();" will call index.phtml but i want to call an another view here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call model view with view you want:

```
     $model = new ViewModel(); 
     $model->setTemplate('edit'); 
     return $model;
```

More info: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.renderer.php-renderer.html

Comment: An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

Comment: Where is your view and how you call it?

Comment: Here is my view located: module\forum\view\forum\index\ edit.phtml

Comment: Controller: module\forum\src\forum\Controller\ IndexController.php

Comment: Sorry i just noticed that you are using 2.0 version updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Within your controller, you can use the `ViewModel`'s `setTemplate` method to change which script will be rendered:

```php
public function someAction()
{
    // do stuff here

    $viewModel = new ViewModel($anArrayOfVariablesForTheView);
    $viewModel->setTemplate('application/view/arbitrary');
    return $viewModel;
}
```

Note that you don't need to specify the `.phtml`.